# 500 Internal Server Error with ASP.NET MVC and Go Daddy

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I know I have seen a lot of posts on an internal server error, but I couldn't find one the answered my question. I created an ASP.NET MVC application. It works fine when I run locally, but when I deploy it I keep getting an internal server error. I called [Go Daddy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_Daddy) and they said it must be something in my code. I know I changed the domain name from when I first set up the website, I don't know if that would change anything.

Comment: Can you get a stack trace? If you can't run the remote copy locally, have you tried temporarily making the <customErrors> change recommended on the error page so that you see the stack trace on the remote version? Can you ask GoDaddy to check the event logs for any errors there?

Comment: Please provide the error with your question.

Comment: internal server error just means an unhandled exception was thrown on the server side, very likely something that prevented your application from even loading, so in most cases you have to look at the dependencies

Answer (score 5):

Try deploying System.Web.Mvc, System.Web.Routing and System.Web.Abstractions with your app (if you aren't already).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410407(VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

There's an infinity of possible reasons as to why you might get this error. You might try to [log the error message in the `Application_Error`](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shay/archive/2009/03/06/real-world-error-hadnling-in-asp-net-mvc-rc2.aspx) method in order to gather more information. The server's event log might also contain useful information.